# What is the domain of the function $\ln\left( \sin \frac{x}{x+1}\right )$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have to calculate the domain of the function $$\ln \left(\sin \frac{x}{x+1}\right).$$
So I have to put $$\sin \frac{x}{x+1}>0 \implies 2k \pi < \frac{x}{x+1} < \pi (1+2k).$$

I should isolate $x$ from this couple of inequalities but I'm afraid I make mistakes because I don't understand why my book suggests as the final result:

$$\left(-  \infty , \frac{- \pi}{\pi -1}\right) \cup  \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{2k \pi}{2k \pi-1}, \frac{-(2k+1)\pi}{(2k+1)\pi-1}\right)\cup  \bigcup_{h=1}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{2h \pi}{2h \pi+1}, \frac{-(2h-1)\pi}{(2h-1)\pi+1}\right) \cup (0, \infty).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sin\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)>0\;\;\iff $$
$$\exists k\in\Bbb Z \;:\; 2k\pi<1-\frac{1}{x+1}<2k\pi+\pi$$
$$\iff$$
$$1-2k\pi-\pi< \frac{1}{x+1}<1-2k\pi$$

For $ k\ne 0$ it gives $$x\in(\frac{1}{1-2k\pi}-1,\frac{1}{1-2k\pi-\pi}-1)$$

For $k=0$, we get

$$1-\pi< \frac{1}{1+x}<0$$ or
$$0<\frac{1}{1+x}<1$$
then
$$1+x<\frac{1}{1-\pi}$$
or
$$1+x>1$$

Answer (score 0):

You can break the inequality $2k\pi<\frac{x}{x+1}<\pi(2k+1)$ in two inequalities $2k\pi<\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $\frac{x}{x+1}<\pi(2k+1)$ then intersect the solutions and finally join the solutios for every $k \in \Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ge 0$m $0\le \frac{x}{x+1}\le 1\lt \pi$.  Therefore $\sin\frac{x}{x+1} \ge 0$, so $x\ge 0$ in domain of function.  For $x\lt 0$, things are more complicated.